# Customizing WIT in TFS 2010 Process Editor

Tags: workitem

Our Release Management process in TFS 2010 is based on branches. for this reason the default bug item  form does not suffice our needs, In Bug item under system Info tab we have "found in build" which lists Labels. and same for "Integrated in Build" . what I need is to have lists of Branches that were created. 
Although the fields allows us to save user entered strings. which I don't want due to Typos.

Is there a way to change the query in WIT editor to list the branches instead of Labels, I did manage to reach to the control using process editor and found that control is being set by this ->Microsoft.VSTS.Build.FoundIn , I am not able to figure it out what would be for branches , or how to create a new one. 
Any help would be appreciated.
/G

Comment: Those aren't labels. Those are  build IDs. Assuming the build corresponds to a branch, they are exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks John for pointing that out , this does help is those cases where I am assigning buildnumberformat with version and branch names is same as version, but what about those cases where branches have names and not same as build number, I would still like to see a way where I could populate the values with branch.

Comment: I name the builds based on branch: "Dev", "Main", "Prod", so I get names like "TeamProject_Dev_20111213.1"

Answer (score 1):

Like John said, it are builds that are stored in those fields. The problem however with that approach is that when the fix for the bug is merged into multiple branches, you cannot see anymore which branches the bug is resolved.

What you can do however is the following: during your checkin process, [mark the work item that you worked on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181410.aspx). This adds a new tracing point, where your bug is tight to a changeset. With [branch visualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd405662.aspx) you can now see in which branches your work item is fixed in.